# Address bar changes in Firefox and Internet exlorer when pressing Ctrl+Enter

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, address-bar

My address bar changes when I go to Google and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Both Firefox and Internet Explorer behave like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may well be spyware/adware. Run a scan with [Avira](http://www.free-av.com/) or other malware removal tool.

Comment: Hai i have bit defender and made a full system scan ...

Comment: Nothing was there

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got some malware. I suggest you go grab [Malwarebytes Anti-malware](http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html?part=dl-10804572&subj=dl&tag=button) (the free one) and [Spybot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/mirrors/index.html). Run these in safe-mode, and run your anti-virus (Avira and AVG are both good and free). You should probably take this opportunity to backup your important files, these things can get to be a serious pain and it'd be nice to not lose your tax info and precious pictures while trying to remove the stuff.

Also, make sure you're all up to date with your windows updates (and get microsoft update to make sure your office apps are up to date). Additionally make sure IE is at version 8 (or at least version 7). And run add-remove programs and remove suspicious evilness.

You may also need to use [HijackThis](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/) to remove evil BHO and auto-runs. Or run `regedit` and check for suspicious things at the following locations:

- [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run]
- [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run Once]
- [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run]
- [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run Once]
- [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Winlogon]
- [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Drivers32]

There are more, but those are the common ones where evil likes to hide.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/change-ctrlenter-behavior-in-firefox/), how to change (or reset) the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> behavior on Firefox, and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffdav/archive/2004/09/09/227502.aspx) on IE8.

Comment: is there some reason for a downvote ?